# K-means clustering using sklearn.cluster

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I came across this tutorial on K-means clustering on [Unsupervised Machine Learning: Flat Clustering](https://pythonprogramming.net/flat-clustering-machine-learning-python-scikit-learn/), and below is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("ggplot")

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

X = np.array([[1,2],[5,8],[1.5,1.8],[1,0.6],[9,11]])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(X)

centroid = kmeans.cluster_centers_
labels = kmeans.labels_

print (centroid)
print(labels)

colors = ["g.","r.","c."]

for i in range(len(X)):
   print ("coordinate:" , X[i], "label:", labels[i])
   plt.plot(X[i][0],X[i][1],colors[labels[i]],markersize=10)

plt.scatter(centroid[:,0],centroid[:,1], marker = "x", s=150, linewidths = 5, zorder =10)

plt.show()
```

In this example, the array has only 2 features `[1,2],[5,8],[1.5,1.8]` etc.

I have tried to replace the `X` with 10 x 750 matrix (750 features) stored in an `np.array()`. 
The graph it created just does not make any sense.

How could I alter the above code to solve my problem?

Comment: Well, you're clustering 750-dimensional data and visualizing only the first two dimensions. It's to be expected that the result doesn't make much sense.

Comment: 10 events with 750 features each? You ain't going to classify that before you do not make a decent feature selection / feature generation. How are you thinking you can cluster 10 points in a 750 dimensional space? This is not going to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Practically, It's impossible to visualize 750 dimension data directly.

But there are other way going around, for example, doing dimention reduction first using [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to a farily low dimention, like 4. Scikit-learn also provides a [function for this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html).

Then you can draw a matrix of plot, with each plot only have two features. Using `Pandas` package, you can draw these plot very easily with [scatter_matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#scatter-matrix-plot) function.

Note that, in your case you only using PCA for visualization, you should still doing K-means clustering on original data, after getting the centroids, doing the PCA for the centroids using the PCA model you create before.

Here is an example plot created by `scatter_matrix` function:
[image]

Comment: scatter_matrix is no longer supported. You can use Seaborn in replace and just do something as simple as import seaborn as sns and then create your dataframe and then do sns.pairplot(df) to create a similar visual as this answer. Works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Visualizing 750 dimensions is hard.

Figure out *independent* of k-means how to visualize.

But don't expect k-means to return meaningful results on such data... it is very sensitive to preprocessing and normalization, and most likely your 750 dimensions are not on the exact same continuous numerical scale.